# Rounding a double value

Tags: java

Hi I need some help in rounding double what is want is stated below:

- If the double value is 18.9000, it will return 18.90
- If the double value is 18.0000, it will return 18
- If the double value is 18.8689, it will return 18.86

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are requesting a particular behavior, you can do the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        String res = formatNum(18.9000); //18.89
        if(res.indexOf(".") < 0)
            System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(res));
        else 
            System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(res));
        res = formatNum(18.0000);//18
        if(res.indexOf(".") < 0)
            System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(res));
        else 
            System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(res));
        res = formatNum(18.8689); //18.86
        if(res.indexOf(".") < 0)
            System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(res));
        else 
            System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(res));
}
private static String formatNum(double num) {
        double n1 = Math.floor(num*100)/100;
        int n2 = (int)Math.round(num);
        return (n1==n2) ? n2+"" : n1+"";
}
```

Comment: not working exactly what i want can you please help i also want If the double value is 18.0000 it will return 18 If the double value is 18.8689 it will return 18.86

Comment: "18.86**8**9 it will return 18.86" sounds like either flooring or truncation, and in the code I see rounding

Comment: @MarkJeronimus Yes, he requested this result. Rounding is just for getting the integer value like the second case. What's your point?

Comment: Hi need one more help from the server i am getting  29.20 but when i debug it i found 0 is not captured from the server have you any idea why this is happening